# How can I continuously stream the content of a SQLite table via command line (adb sqlite3) instead of manually pulling it?

Tags: android, android-emulator, sqlite, adb

I have a batch script which shows me the content of an SQLite db table on a real device:

```
  @ECHO OFF
  SET packageId=com.brightideahub.motorassistant
  SET databaseName=test_event_data.db
  SET tableName=test_table
  adb shell "su -c 'sqlite3 -header -column /data/data/%packageId%/databases/%databaseName% \"SELECT * FROM %tableName%\"'"
  pause
```

The problem is that every time the DB changes I have to re-run this script to see the changes.
 **Is there a way to stream the content of the DB, similarly how logcat messages show real-time?**

Also, I have been going through the options available for the sqlite3 command. Can anyone explain what the *-batch* and *-interactive* options do exactly, and whether they would be any use for what I am trying to achieve?

```
  sqlite3 -help
  Usage: sqlite3 [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL]
  FILENAME is the name of an SQLite database. A new database is created
  if the file does not previously exist.
  OPTIONS include:
     -bail                stop after hitting an error
     -batch               force batch I/O
     -column              set output mode to 'column'
     -cmd COMMAND         run "COMMAND" before reading stdin
     -csv                 set output mode to 'csv'
     -echo                print commands before execution
     -init FILENAME       read/process named file
     -[no]header          turn headers on or off
     -help                show this message
     -html                set output mode to HTML
     -interactive         force interactive I/O
     -line                set output mode to 'line'
     -list                set output mode to 'list'
     -nullvalue TEXT      set text string for NULL values. Default ''
     -separator SEP       set output field separator. Default: '|'
     -stats               print memory stats before each finalize
     -version             show SQLite version
     -vfs NAME            use NAME as the default VFS
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of `logcat` is a serial stream of new data, which makes its ability to "stream" pretty straight forward. Updates to a sqlite3 database are not a serial stream of updates, they're a random access collection of updates -- which means there's nothing to stream in any logical sense.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I realised that, using the streaming terminology was probably confusing and not appropriate here..... I ended up checking the DB for changes periodically and write to/update stdout if the data has been changed...